# Hudson Build Server - problem with shutdown slave machine

Tags: hudson, batch-file, shutdown, slave, system-shutdown

I am new to Hudson and I have a question. 
I'm trying to build some jobs on dumb slave and after that I need to shutdown that slave.(the machine). However, there is the following issue: I've tryed many ways,
using "shutdown /s /t 120", starting .bat file copyed at the slabe with this content, even starting .jar file to shutdown. And the result is the negative. When running "shutdown /s /t 120" I receive 
"'shutdown' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.".
Does anybody solved such issue or have any suggestions?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `cmd.exe /c shutdown /r /t 120`